# converting datetime mysql with timezone from same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following columns (simplified): openingtime | timezone

This tables holds opening times. The datetime is in the timezone my server is in, timezone is the timezone of the location the opening time is for. I would like to query the datetime column ending up with the local time.

Example data:

```
2022-07-08 11:00:00 | Europe/London
```

My server is in Europe/Paris so the expected output would be 2022-07-08 10:00:00

The following only gives my NULL as results:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(openingtime, 'Europe/Paris', timezone) 
FROM openingtimes
```

Answer (score 0):

To use [CONVERT_TZ()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html) you need to install the time-zone tables otherwise MySQL returns NULL.

To load time zone:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

After time zone loaded:

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.25    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2022-07-08 11:00:00', 'Europe/London','GMT') ;
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT_TZ('2022-07-08 11:00:00', 'Europe/London','GMT') |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 2022-07-08 10:00:00                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will ask my hosting provider.